# How do I install Exscript for Python 3.5 under Windows x86

Tags: python, exscript

Can anybody help with instructions to install this for Python 3.5 x32 running on Windows?
I think that the usual way (pip install exscript) attempts to install the wrong version

Here is the error that I am getting

```
Collecting exscript
Using cached Exscript-2.3.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-pe80jvo3\exscript\setup.py", line 4, in 
from Exscript.version import version
File "C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-pe80jvo3\exscript\Exscript_init_.py", line 34, in 
from Exscript.Queue import Queue
File "C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-pe80jvo3\exscript\Exscript\Queue.py", line 35, in 
from Exscript.Logger import logger_registry
File "C:\Users\MyUserA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-pe80jvo3\exscript\Exscript\Logger.py", line 27, in 
from itertools import chain, ifilter
ImportError: cannot import name 'ifilter'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-pe80jvo3\exscript\
```

There is a Python 3.0 branch but I can not figure out how to install it
https://github.com/knipknap/exscript/tree/py3

Comment: It's not supported, and the python 3 branch is unfinished. Read the descriptions of the brunch.

Comment: It says updated three days ago https://github.com/knipknap/exscript/branches/active  where do I read the description you are talking about

Comment: Updated three days ago doesn't mean it's finished and bug free. That's why I said *unfinished* and not *non-existent*

Comment: First off, if you go to version.py it says `__version__ = 'DEVELOPMENT'`

Comment: Sorry I am not very familiar with git and branches and all. That is why I asked. I thought that since the developers uploaded that branch it is viable code

Comment: Unfortunately not, github is only simple platform for multiple developers to contribute together and that the users can see all their changes.

Comment: Then shouldn't pip say that there is no exscript 2.3 for Python 3.x  instead of just trying to install something? I am assuming that pip is searching the repositories for something that is compatible with the python version that is making the call. Am I wrong ?

Comment: See the answer I provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty hard to explain in the comments, so I'll write an answer that includes everything I talked about.

First: the module in question, Exscript, is still in development for python 3 support, which means that it is not fully functional and bug free at the moment. Even it though said *updated yesterday* in GitHub, it means that the last time it was changed was yesterday not that it was released final yesterday. You can still download and use the development version if you want, just comment down below and I'll show you how. 
To see if it's final, you can go to the version.py in GitHub and check the __version__, currently it's set to 'development', and they will change it to 'final' if it's final.

Second: the reason for pip to trying to install the python 2 version is because the developers were lazy so they only uploaded a `.tar` file containing the package with a setup.py file in it, which pip automatically downloaded and try to setup it up for you. Look [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Exscript/2.3). Normally, packages are stored in a `.whl` file stating which python version it's for and which OS it's supported, pip can recognize these but not `.tar` files since they do not contain any information regarding whats so ever.

In conclusion, I would not recommend getting Exscript for python 3 right now since it doesn't fully work.

Comment: Thanks for the above. I ended up using Python 2.7. I just needed Qt5 but that does not work with Python 2.7 so I settled for Qt4.